# Zabbix NFS monitoring

Tags: monitoring, nfs, performance-monitoring, zabbix, system-monitoring

How would you monitor response of mounted NFS directory with Zabbix?  I'm thinking about something like

```
$ time /bin/ls -U /path/to/nfs
```

(I think the output from `nfsstat(8)` relates less with user experience.)

Comment: You can probably wrap it in bash, a la https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-the-time-command-to-a-file-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `ioping`... But I probably wouldn't monitor NFS performance at that layer, but rather from the NFS server itself, as most causes of user experience issues would ultimately be rooted in networking or the host server.

Comment: Sometimes NFS server isn't yours and you want to monitor client experience.

Comment: Maybe, but that wasn't communicated by the OP.

Comment: Well, both of you are right :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a look on available Zabbix solutions: http://monitoringartist.github.io/zabbix-searcher/#nfs

Comment: This is not really what I was looking for, but great source of information.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about availability or utilization?

Use iostat to monitor NFS utilization:

Ubuntu/Debian:

```
apt-get install sysstat
nfsiostat 1 100
```

or Redhat/Centos:

```
yum install sysstat
iostat -xn 1 100
```